# Alchemy's getNFTMetadata does not return title and description for freshly minted NFT on OpenSea

Tags: nft, alchemy

I connected to the testnet OpenSea and minted an NFT on Rinkeby.

After that I called alchemy's getNFTMetadata and it did return some data, but "title" and "description" were empty, even though it contained other information, including "tokenUri".

There was and error in the body `Token uri responded with a non 200 response code`, but I tried calling the `tokenUri.gateway` and it responded with correct JSON.

After several hours getNFTMetadata started returning both "title" and "description".

Is this an Alchemy bug, works as intended or I'm missing some parameters?

This is the request and response (since this is an old NFT, if you try calling Alchemy it returns correct results)

`https://eth-rinkeby.alchemyapi.io/v2/demo/getNFTMetadata?contractAddress=0x88b48f654c30e99bc2e4a1559b4dcf1ad93fa656&tokenId=0x51255A4131A2E15481A91159334BBEDC4CE144C1000000000000020000000001`

```
{
    "contract": {
        "address": "0x88b48f654c30e99bc2e4a1559b4dcf1ad93fa656"
    },
    "id": {
        "tokenId": "0x51255a4131a2e15481a91159334bbedc4ce144c1000000000000020000000001",
        "tokenMetadata": {
            "tokenType": "ERC1155"
        }
    },
    "title": "",
    "description": "",
    "tokenUri": {
        "raw": "https://testnets-api.opensea.io/api/v1/metadata/0x88B48F654c30e99bc2e4A1559b4Dcf1aD93FA656/0x{id}",
        "gateway": "https://testnets-api.opensea.io/api/v1/metadata/0x88B48F654c30e99bc2e4A1559b4Dcf1aD93FA656/0x51255a4131a2e15481a91159334bbedc4ce144c1000000000000020000000001"
    },
    "media": [
        {
            "raw": "",
            "gateway": ""
        }
    ],
    "metadata": {
        "metadata": [],
        "attributes": []
    },
    "timeLastUpdated": "2022-08-17T14:03:51.814Z",
    "error": "Token uri responded with a non 200 response code"
}
```

Comment: I got a similar problem. This bug exists only for ERC-1155 tokens. Tokens with ERC-721 work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your testnet from Rinkeby to Goerli. Rinkeby is not supported.

Full answer is here: https://docs.alchemy.com/discuss/6334c676cc14a50040e61969